# Solving partial differential equation.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I want to solve this kind of equation: $${A∂f(x, t)\over ∂t} = {Bd^2f(x, t)\over \mathrm dx^2}$$ I tried to solve this equation in this way: $f(x, t) = a(x)b(t)$. But can I solve this more general?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! I want to remind you that it is generally preferred you include context when asking a question here (which can include: where this problem came from, your own attempts, and a *specific* idea as to where you're stuck) - it also lets us help you better! As is, your question is little more than an isolated problem, and thus likely to get a lot of downvotes and closed. Feel free to edit the context into your post though! Here's a useful link: [asking a good question](https://goo.gl/11Cojp).

Comment: this is heat PDE. Use separation of variables as you started. Need boundary and initial condition. There are many examples on the internet of how to solve this. without boundary conditions given, you can't obtain solution, since the form of the solution depends on type of boundary conditions.

Comment: Sorry, yes I have boundary condition here. I know that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x, 0) = g(x)$

Comment: so you are saying this is a semi-infinite domain? i.e. for $0<x<\infty$? You need to specify complete and exact specification of the PDE. Also not a good idea to use $f$ for the dependent variable. a common symbol is $u$

Comment: You should include any boundary and initial conditions into the question since they provide context

Answer (score 0):

If $A,B$ are just (nonzero) constants (i.e., this is just a heat equation), then yes it can be solved in other ways. For example, the Fourier transform would do the trick.

If $A,B$ aren't constants, then I'd need some more info on them in order to give you an answer.

Edit: If you're aim is to solve the BVP, then the approach you mention (separation of variables) is probably the way to go. In some domains (including an interval as in your example) you can use a Green function, but you'll probably have to use separation of variables to solve for it, so I'm not sure you're going to escape that approach in the long run.

Comment: They are pure, nonzero constants. And the boundary are $f(0) = 0$, $f(x, 0) = g(x)$.

Comment: You mean $f(0,t)=0$?

Comment: No, in my case $f(x, 0) = sin(πx/a)$, where $a$ is just nonzero constant.

Comment: I understand you have an inhomogeneous IC. I was just trying to get at what you meant by $f(0)=0$. Does the problem have homogeneous BCs?

Comment: No, it has not.

Comment: Then, what do you mean by $f(0)=0$?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is incorrect. Suppose I have function $g(x)$, that has boundary $0<x<a$ and $g(0) = 0$, $g(a) = 0$. This function describes wavefunction of particle. Then in time $t=0$ this function starts to envolve in time through this partial differential equation, that I wrote. I need to know how does this function envolve in time. We know that in time $t=0$ our time-dependent function $f(x, 0) = g(x)$. We also know that $f(x, t)$ can now be in gap $0<x<∞$.